# Bad file descriptor in C

Tags: c, pipe

I'm trying to write a code for C program: in the parent process the command is given, then it's sent through a pipe to a child process, which deals with the command.

The response is: **write (): Bad file descriptor**

I think I'm not closing the wrong end of the pipe... Not sure anymore. Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
  int main (int argc, char **argv) {

  ...

  int filedes[2];       

  if (pipe (filedes) < 0)
    error_fatal ("pipe ()");

  if ((pid = fork ()) < 0)
    error_fatal ("fork ()");
  else
    if (pid == 0) {

      if (close (filedes[0]) < 0)
    error_fatal ("close ()");

      while (1) {

      FD_ZERO (&read_set);
      FD_SET (filedes[1], &read_set);

    sleep (3);

    if (select (filedes[1] + 1, &read_set, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0)
      error_fatal ("select ()");
    else {

      if (FD_ISSET (filedes[1], &read_set)) {

        if (read (filedes[1], &d, 1) != 1)
          error_fatal ("read ()");
        else
          if (d == EOF)
        break;
        else {

          switch (d) {

        case 'd' : if (system ("date") < 0) error_fatal ("system ()"); break;
        case 'u' : if (system ("users") < 0) error_fatal ("system ()"); break;
        default: printf ("No such command.\n"); break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
      }
    }
    else {

      if (close (filedes[1]) < 0)
    error_fatal ("close ()");

      while ((c = fgetc (stdin)) != EOF) {

    if (write (filedes[0], &c, 1) < 0)
      error_fatal ("write ()");

      }
    }

  exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I only swapped the indexes, and it works. 
Missed this part...

**Two file descriptors are returned through the filedes argument: filedes[0] is open for reading, and filedes[1] is open for writing. The output of filedes[1] is the input for filedes[0].**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem described in it was caused by erroneous use of variables that was detected and resolved by the OP.